# Conjectured integral for Catalan's constant

Tags: nt.number-theory

Numerical evidence suggests:

$$ \int_0^{\frac12}\int_0^{\frac12}\frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2} dy \, dx= \frac{G}{3}\qquad (1)$$

Couldn't find the indefinite integral, though maple simplifies (1) to

$$ \int _{0}^{1/2}\!-\arctan \left( 1/2\,{\frac {1}{\sqrt {-1+{x}^{2}}}} \right) {\frac {1}{\sqrt {-1+{x}^{2}}}}{dx}$$

> Is (1) true?

Comment: Rewriting the integrand as a geometric series might help.

Comment: Mathematica returns $2G$ for $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (1-x^2-y^2)^{-1}dxdy$, as a side note.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson for yours Maple returns complex number, might be wrong.

Comment: @Joro: Yeah, Mathematica does something strange here I think.

Comment: There is a simple formula for Catalan involving arctan: $$\int_0^1{\arctan x\over x}\,dx=G$$ It's given as Exercise 6.2.7 in Boros & Moll, Irresistible Integrals. They point to Adamchik, Integrals and series representations for Catalan's constant, and Bradley, Representations of Catalan's constant, for more formulas. The Adamchik reference might be http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/catalan/catalan.htm which has many formulas for $G$ but nothing quite like what you want.

Comment: The Bradley paper is available at http://math.umemat.maine.edu/~bradley/papers/c1.ps though again there's nothing that matches your question exactly.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for the reference.

Comment: can you rewrite your last integral in terms of functions of a real variable?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik don't know. There is great cancellation of imaginary stuff if it is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mathematica confirms the following:

Change the integral to polar coordinates to get

$$\frac{(1)}{2} = \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_0^{\sec(\theta)/2} \frac{1}{1-r^2}r\ dr\ d\theta = \frac{G}{6}.$$

Comment: Thank you. Is there closed form for the indefinite integral?

Comment: Yes, but it's a pretty large expression involving terms such as Log[1 + 1/2 (1 + I Sqrt[3]) E^(2 I t)] and PolyLog[2, -(1/2) (1 + I Sqrt[3]) E^(2 I t)] (where the outer integral runs from 0 to $t$).

Comment: Hm, it doesn't find closed form without integral?

Answer (score 10):

There is also an interpretation of this integral in terms of hyperbolic geometry. In hyperbolic geometry, Catalan's constant $G$ is one quarter the (three dimensional) volume of a regular ideal octahedron (or the volume of an ideal tetrahedron with dihedral angles $\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{4}$, and $\frac{\pi}{4}$).

If $\Gamma$ is the group of orientation preserving isometries of a tessellation of $\mathbb{H}^3$ by regular ideal octahedra (aka $PGL(2,O_1)$), the quotient of $\mathbb{H}^3/\Gamma$ has volume: $$\frac{G}{6}=\int_0 ^\frac{1}{2}\int_0 ^\frac{1}{2}\int_\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} ^\infty \frac{1}{z^3} dz dy dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0 ^\frac{1}{2}\int_0 ^\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-x^2-y^2} dy dx .$$

A decent reference for understanding this observation is Neumann and Reid's [Notes on Adams' small volume orbifolds (page 312)](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=WrKfdUgvtWIC&pg=PA311&lpg=PA311&dq=Notes%20on%20Adams%27%20small%20volume%20orbifolds&source=bl&ots=Fb-Spzzahv&sig=0I5fvT9lxzFTM-R-jVRd-WsYtRA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ioYiVIPDDsnt8AWY2ILIDw&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Notes%20on%20Adams'%20small%20volume%20orbifolds&f=false). Although not directly stated, their method relies on the observation that a certain manifold, the Whitehead link complement, is well known to be isometric to a regular ideal octahedron with faces identified in pairs, as noted above this means it has volume $4G$. The orbifold we are interested in is a 24 fold quotient of this manifold, and so it has volume $\frac{G}{6}$. The geometry of the orbifold is described in Colin Adams' paper [Noncompact 3-Orbifolds of Small Volume](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=WrKfdUgvtWIC&pg=PA1&dq=Noncompact%20hyperbolic%203-orbifolds%20of%20small%20volume&hl=en&sa=X&ei=hIkiVOn8AYT_8QWV7YLIBQ&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Noncompact%20hyperbolic%203-orbifolds%20of%20small%20volume&f=false) (see figure 6(c) and Theorem 5.2).

However, an early reference is Borel's paper: [Commensurability classes and volumes of hyperbolic 3-manifolds](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/ASNSP/ASNSP_1981_4_8_1/ASNSP_1981_4_8_1_1_0/ASNSP_1981_4_8_1_1_0.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. Is there closed form for the indefinite integral?

Comment: It is not known whether $G$ is irrational. Does it matter for hyperbolic geometry if this volume is rational or not?

Comment: I don't know of one. The closest thing I can think of in terms of resembling a closed form motivated by the hyperbolic geometry, which would involve Clausen function of order 2 (aka the Lobachevsky function).

Comment: In some sense, it doesn't matter. Volume is often used a ``crude'' invariant to tell two hyperbolic manifolds apart. However, it would be intriguing to find a hyperbolic manifold with a rational volume. In fact, such a question is related to one of the last remaining open problems on W. Thurston's famous list: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1982-06-03/S0273-0979-1982-15003-0/S0273-0979-1982-15003-0.pdf (See section 6 question 23). Looking at it in that light, it would be a very big deal if $G$ were rational.

Comment: Thank you for the education. Is this known $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (1-x^2-y^2)^{-1}dxdy=?$? According to comments Mathematica claims it $2G$. In Maple after the simplification get $2G -i \pi^2/4 $. Numerically in mpmath it appears unstable.

Comment: Unfortunately for this expanded domain, the correspondence breaks down. The triple integral in the answer requires the domain to be in upper half space. However, there are (x,y) where $(1-x^2-y^2) < 0$ is negative on this domain, which would correspond to negative or (worse) undefined $z$ values in the triple integral.

Answer (score 6):

After some trick substitutions, I've put the integral in the form:

$$\int_0^{\pi/6}{\coth^{-1}{(2\,\cos{t})}dt}$$

Mathematica (version 8) then returns the exact value $\frac{G}{3}$. A nice definite integral for Catalan's constant, anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The proof of (1),  sketched in http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/catalan.pdf, goes as follows.

With the substitution $x=x^\prime/2,\,y=y^\prime/2$, the integral (1) takes the form (we have omitted the primes) 
$$I_2=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dx\,dy}{4-x^2-y^2}.$$
Due to the $x\leftrightarrow y$ exchange symmetry of the integrand, 
$$I_2=2\iint\limits_\Delta \frac{dx\,dy}{4-x^2-y^2},$$
where the triangular integration domain $\Delta$ is the lower half of the unit square $0\le x\le 1,\,0\le y\le 1$. Let us introduce the polar coordinates, as suggested by Aeryk, $x=r\cos{\theta},\,y=r\sin{\theta}$. Then
$$I_2=\int\limits_0^{\pi/4}d\theta\int\limits_0^{1/cos{\theta}}\frac{2r}{4-r^2}dr=\int\limits_0^{\pi/4}\ln{\frac{4\cos^2{\theta}}{4\cos^2{\theta}-1}}\,d\theta.$$
Now, by using $\sin{3\theta}=\sin{\theta}(3\cos^2{\theta}-\sin^2{\theta})=\sin{\theta}(4\cos^2{\theta}-1)$, we cen rewrite the above integral in the form $$I_2=\int\limits_0^{\pi/4}\ln{\frac{4\cos^2{\theta}\sin{\theta}}{\sin{3\theta}}}\,d\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{2}+2I_C+I_S-I_{3S},$$
where the integrals $$I_S=\int\limits_0^{\pi/4}\ln{\sin{\theta}}\,d\theta=-\frac{1}{2}\,G-\frac{\pi}{4}\,\ln{2},\;I_C=\int\limits_0^{\pi/4}\ln{\cos{\theta}}\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\,G-\frac{\pi}{4}\,\ln{2}$$
were calculated in http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/catalan.pdf, while for $I_{3S}$ we have
$$I_{3S}=\int\limits_0^{\pi/4}\ln{\sin{3\theta}}\,d\theta=\frac{1}{3}
\int\limits_0^{3\pi/4}\ln{\sin{\theta}}\,d\theta=\frac{1}{3}\left[
\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\ln{\sin{\theta}}\,d\theta+
\int\limits_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/4}\ln{\sin{\theta}}\,d\theta\right].$$
The substitution $\alpha=-(\pi/2-\theta)$ shows that the second integral equals to $I_C$, while for the first integral the following result can be found in http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/catalan.pdf
$$\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\ln{\sin{\theta}}\,d\theta=
\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\ln{\cos{\theta}}\,d\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\ln{2}.$$
Therefore
$$I_{3S}=\frac{1}{3}\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\ln{2}+\frac{1}{2}\,G-\frac{\pi}{4}\,\ln{2}\right]=\frac{1}{6}\,G-\frac{\pi}{4}\,\ln{2},$$ and
$$I_2=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln{2}+2\left(\frac{1}{2}\,G-\frac{\pi}{4}\,\ln{2}\right)+\left(-\frac{1}{2}\,G-\frac{\pi}{4}\,\ln{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{6}\,G-\frac{\pi}{4}\,\ln{2}\right)=\frac{G}{3}.$$
By the similar method, the following result was proved in http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/catalan.pdf
$$I_1=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dx\,dy}{2-x^2-y^2}=G.$$

Comment: Thanks. The paper references the question in `8.`.